# How to delete a row in a grid Table populated with json Model? SAPUI5

Tags: javascript, json, sapui5

I need to delete a row in a table who is bind with jModel when I click in the trash button.

[image]

This is my data:

```
_data: {
            requestSpecific: [{nArt= "A002", name="Computador, quantity=2},{},{...}],
            items: [],
            partner: [],
            vatGroups: [],
            countries: [],
            totals: [],
            ttlstotais: []
        },
```

model name is jModel.
Maybe I have some mistakes in the model in here, but it's rigth on the code.

The table is a grid table in Single mode.

This is my event for the button "trash".

```
onDelArtigoPress: function (oEvent) {
            var iIndex = oTable.getSelectedIndex();
            var jData = this.jModel.getProperty("/requestSpecific");
            var sMsg;
            if (iIndex < 0) {
                sMsg = "Please, select an item to be deleted";
            } else {
               //// 1st delete the object in the model 
               //// 2nd refresh the model, It will automaticaly update the table
            }
}
```

I don't know how to do the 1st step.
I know that I need to use the splice prototype, but I don't know how to get the position of the object in the array (jModel).

If you can help me ....!

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

```
onDelArtigoPress: function (oEvent) {
        var oTable = this.byId("tableArtigoId");
        var iIndex = oTable.getSelectedIndex(); 
        var sMsg;
        if (iIndex < 0) {
            sMsg = "Sem nenhuma linha selecionada";
            MessageToast.show(sMsg);
        } else {
            var oData = this._data.requestSpecific;
            oData.splice(iIndex, 1);
            this.jModel.setProperty("/requestSpecific", oData);

        }

    },
```